# Styling unusual html tags! Why is this possible?

Tags: html, css, stylesheet, frontend

Today I found out something weird regarding the way `CSS` works.
Basically I tried to apply some styles to `head`, `title` and `script`.

I was buffled to find out that this thing worked, so I'm obviously trying to find out why would such a thing be possible.

I got some code going on: [here](http://embed.plnkr.co/GN8GxdDfjdM5IgpKEru0/preview).

I even tried this thing on a local project and it behaves the same, so it's not something related to plunker.

Any clues?

HTML Markup:

```
<head>
    <title>Am I styled?</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <script>console.log("Stylish!");</script>
</head>
```

CSS:

```
title {
  color: red;
  display: block;
  font-size: 30px;
}

head {
  display: block;
  border: 3px solid black;
}

script {
  display: block;
  color: green;
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't just rely on 3rd party sites to host your code. post a sample here too

Comment: This is old news, but makes for some fun times along with `contenteditable`: http://jsfiddle.net/HfcP4/show (edit the css to style it, `enter` inserts `<br>`so keep it on a line)

Comment: @xec it may be *old news*, but it still is amazing :D

Answer (score 4):

It is possible because there is no good reason for it to be impossible.

To make it impossible there would have to be special casing to treat the elements differently. That means more work and more complexity (and thus more opportunity for bugs) both in the browsers that handle HTML and CSS and in the HTML and CSS specifications.

Comment: IE8- do not have the same behaviour (..predictable, I know). Isn't this behaviour supposed to be in a certain spec somewere?

Comment: @gion_13 — IE8 is buggy. The specs are the HTML and CSS specs, they don't say that any element should be ignored for the purposes of styling.

Comment: @gion_13 The whatwg worked out some specs for rendering, this is the closest i found: http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/rendering.html#hidden-elements ... note that `<noscript>` should ignore css rules displaying it (if script is enabled) and indeed: it does http://jsfiddle.net/HfcP4/1/ -- but as far as `<style>` goes, it's just hidden by the default (user agent) css.

Comment: @xec Thanks for the link, I guess I was thinking like 10 years ago *only the body gets rendered!*

Answer (score 1):

It is possible because browsers have been developed to process HTML elements more uniformly. For example, the “unusual styling” does not work on IE 8 and older. In modern browsers, rendering is more systematically based on CSS concepts; all elements have all CSS properties, and the value of the `display` property controls the overall way of rendering the element. For `head` and possibly for its children, the default is `display: none`. As you’ve seen, this can be overridden.

Marginally, the motivation behind this may also have included the idea that authors could make some use of styling elements that are normally invisible. For example, a page that discusses CSS might wish to show its own style settings, as set in a `style` element`, simply by making that element visible and suitably formatted, e.g.`style { display: block; white-space: pre }`.